# SlidingMenu creates delay before activity shown

Tags: android, performance, slidingmenu

I'm trying to add SlidingMenu to my Activity. My code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    informationMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    informationMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    informationMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    informationMenu.setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    informationMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    informationMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    informationMenu.setMenu(R.layout.main_info);
    informationMenu.setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);


    informationMenu.setOnOpenListener(new SlidingMenu.OnOpenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            helpMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
        }
    });

    informationMenu.setOnClosedListener(new SlidingMenu.OnClosedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClosed() {
            helpMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
        }
    });
}
```

But after adding this I often can see black screen for 1 or 2 seconds before my activity starts. I've tryed to use AsyncTask to create menu, but I didn't recive big improvment. Is it possible to fix it?

P.S. I'm using this lib: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: I'm using the same library but having no issues like this. Maybe you're doing to much work in the activities themselves before it can draw its layout?

Comment: but when I remove menu creation everything works ok (without this delay)

Comment: have this same problem. i think it has to do with the content on the main activity. but even some very simple activities seem to have a slight hiccup to them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this at every Activity, or in some base/parent Activity?

In my own project, I have this kind of code only once, in the BaseActivity.

Furthermore, I only use this;

```
           // set the Behind View
            setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
            FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFrag = new MenuListFragment();
            t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
            t.commit();

            // Customize the SlidingMenu
            SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
            sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
            sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
            sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
            sm.setBehindScrollScale(0.25f);
            sm.setFadeDegree(0.25f);
```

You could see how I do it at https://code.google.com/p/my-curriculum-vitae/source/checkout , its been a while since i worked on this so not 100% sure anymore.

Comment: Now I added slidingmenu only to launch activity so it appears only once. I can see that you uses approach with extending SlidingActivity. It's a bit difficult for me to test this way because my activity already extends OrmLiteBaseActivity